# How to store more than 5k items in List.How to deal List Throttling issue in JSOM Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I have a list in SharePoint online having more than 5000 items. How to deal it with JSOM or REST API.

Comment: This can be done with proper filtering/indexing. What do you do with JSOM / REST api? Please add more info.

Comment: Please refer this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

Comment: Or just google the exact verbiage in your question.  There are countless articles, posts, and advice already published over the years dealing with List View Threshold.  If you need advice for a very specific scenario that has not already been published about, then you will need to give us those specifics.

Answer (score 0):

In general, any query in JSOM/CSOM can work around the List View Threshold by setting the [`RowLimit`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj262602(v%3Doffice.15)) to some number under 5,000.  If you actually need to retrieve more than 5,000 of the items, you will need to use the [`ListItemCollectionPosition`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245754(v%3Doffice.15)) to "page" through the results in "chunks" so that any given queryExecute never exceeds the List View Threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to create index column and then use it in Rest API endpoint or Caml, please check the similiar question here:

[SharePoint Online: REST API for List, calling Filters and limit the return items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362465/sharepoint-online-rest-api-for-list-calling-filters-and-limit-the-return-items)

Another suggestion is to check the ItemsCount in the logic and use the $top parameter in Rest to control the items returned less than 5000:

[How to read more than 5000 list items in office 365/ SharePoint 2013](http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-read-more-than-5000-list-items-in-office-365sharepoint-2013/)